# Can I CopyFile after LockFileEx it?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, multiprocessing

So, I am trying to Copy a File after locked it! But I got the GetLastError() = 32 - "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

By order, Is the same process using the file because it was locked first. I am working with multi-process application and using LockFileEx exclude the other process handle the equal file information . Besides, I have been reading the LockFileEx documentation and did not find something related to impossibility to CopyFile after lock it.

```
HANDLE cfile;
bool alreadyExistFile = FALSE;
OVERLAPPED sOverlapped;
sOverlapped.Offset = 1;
sOverlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;

cfile = CreateFile(TEXT("CounterSeedAssincrono.csv.csv"),
         GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);

LockFileEx(cfile, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK |
         LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY, 0, 10000, 0, &sOverlapped);

CopyFile(TEXT("CounterSeedAssincrono.csv"),
     TEXT("CounterSeedAssincrono_A.csv"), alreadyExistFile);

if (alreadyExistFile == FALSE)
    cout << "CopyFile Failed -> " << GetLastError() << endl;

UnlockFileEx(cfile, 0, 10000, 0, &sOverlapped);

CloseHandle(cfile);
```

Someone know if it is possible to do what i am trying? I am using Windows and VS 2015.

Comment: Quote: "If the locking process opens the file a second time, it cannot access the specified region through this second handle until it unlocks the region."  Yup, that's what CopyFile does.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I solve the problem just CopyFile after all instruction, but my logic problem keep on. Actually, I need something similar to file "rename", if I use just a function rename more than one process can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You call `CreateFile` passing 0 as `dwShareMode` flags therefore blocking all read and write access to it until this file handle is closed. And `LockFileEx` is not really necessary.

PS `cfile` is left uninitialized, did you mean `cfile = CreateFile(...`? Also `GetLastError` must be called immediately after failed call, otherwise the value returned might be altered. And you don't check result of `LockFileEx` and other methods at all.

Comment: I just putted LockFileEx after realized that there were two process accessing the file content simultaneously. But, I will check again. About the PS, you are right, sorry i forgot but just corrected. In my original code I am care about call flag LockFileEx.